# PostGIS - Tables UNION

Tags: postgis, union, st-intersects

I have three tables (`Table_1`, `Table_2`, `Table_3`) with the same fields:
`geom`, `Field_a`, `Field_b`, `Field_c`, `Field_d`.

I want to `SELECT` these tables so that all their rows appear but I want do not want rows where geometries intersects with other rows from other tables.

I mean that I do not want intersection duplicates in my new table.

Here is the code I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1 AS T1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table_2 AS T2 WHERE ST_Intersects(T2.geom, T1.geom) IS FALSE
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table_3 AS T3 WHERE ST_Intersects(T3.geom, T2.geom) IS FALSE
AND ST_Intersects(T3.geom, T1.geom)
```

I get the message `Missing entry` on the first `ST_Intersects()` on `T1.geom`.
I don't know what does this mean.

Comment: You need to change your logic. Right now your first UNION statement, if it had a JOIN to reference T1, would repeat each T2 which didn't overlap T1, for every T1 row (polynomial expansion). The second would be even worse (N * M *L). Using  NOT EXISTS could get this job none, but the performance will be abysmal.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking about creating a new table and then delete the rows which overlaps, I would just have to cross join the table with itself right ?

Comment: Indeed, though with an `and j.objid > t.objid` constraint